# Windows 8: Launch application on logoff

Tags: windows-8, group-policy, c#, winforms

I created an application (.NET Windows Forms) which shall be launched after a user presses the "Logoff" key in Windows 8. I created a gpo in my domain environment which works in Windows 7. However, Windows 8 shows instantly the logoff screen and there is no chance for my application to pop up. Is there some kind of GPO that prevents the application from showing up?

The purpose of the application is to show users their projects and they have to tell the application how long they worked for a specific project. This would be nice if this works on logoff.

Comment: For troubleshooting, you may want to add a simple file write to c:\temp or alike a the start up of your WinForms app, that way you know if it's being launched correctly (or not).

Comment: @FRules - I removed my comment since it wasn't complete.  As (we) discovered your script was working it was just hidden due to the subtle change in the position of the logon/logoff window with Windows 8+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 8 logoff screen is the topmost window, and that's why you can't see Windows launched during Logoff.

A fix that has been [suggested to work](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79c57e66-69f6-4d96-b056-52ff61411e74/windows-8-logoff-script-problem?forum=w8itprogeneral) is to enable the `Display instructions in logoff scripts as they run` group policy in `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Scripts`

> **Description**
>
> Displays the instructions in logoff scripts as they run.
>
> Logoff scripts are batch files of instructions that run when the user
>   logs off. By default, the system does not display the instructions in
>   the logoff script.
>
> If you enable this policy, the system displays each instruction in the
>   logoff script as it runs. The instructions appear in a command window.
>   This setting is designed for advanced users.
>
> If you disable this policy or do not configure it, the instructions
>   are suppressed.

Comment: Did this behavior change with Windows 8?  It just seems odd they would change the logoff procedure in a significant way unless it was just a subtle change?

Comment: To answer my own comment.  It does appear there was a subtle change by making the logoff screen the topmost window.  I am sure there is a reason for this change.  Worth pointing out the logon screen is also the topmost window, so "Display instructions in logon scripts" policy would have to be used if this application was ran on a logon event